# finding all the words in a text file appearing in another text file

Tags: text-processing, file-comparison

Suppose I have two files `a.txt` and `b.txt`.
I want to find all the words in `a.txt` which appear in `b.txt`.

Is there a specific command to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `bash`, `zsh` and some implementations of `ksh`:

```
comm -12 <(tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]' < a.txt | sort -u) \
         <(tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]' < b.txt | sort -u)
```

There, *word* is a sequence of non-spacing character (beware that with GNU `tr`, that doesn't work with multi-byte spacing characters).

`comm` finds the common lines between two sorted files. Without options, it prints 3 columns: the lines only in file1, the lines only in file2, and the lines common to both. You add `-1`, `-2`, `-3` to remove the corresponding columns from the output. So `comm -12` only leaves the third column (the common lines).

`tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]'` **tr**ansliterate any **s**equence of characters of class `space` into newlines, to put every *word* on its own line.

`sort -u` sorts and removes duplicates from `tr`'s output.

Process substitution `<(...)` pipes the outputs of the `tr|sort` commands to `comm`.

---

With `zsh`:

```
w1=($(<a.txt)) w2=($(<b.txt))
print -rl -- ${(u)${w1:*w2}}
```

There, *word* is a sequence of characters other than space, tab, nul and newline (with the default value of `$IFS`).

`$(<a.txt)` is an optimised version of `$(cat a.txt)` where `zsh` reads the content of the file by itself without invoking `cat`, since it's not quoted, it undergoes word splitting (but not globbing contrary to other shells).

So `w1` and `w2` are arrays containing all the words in `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

`${w1:*w2}` is a zsh operator that gives the intersection of two arrays (the elements common to both). `(u)` is a parameter expansion flag that retains unique elements (removes duplicates).

`print -rl` prints each argument one per line.

Comment: sorry, my fault now it is ok

Answer (score 2):

```
# Create dummy text file containing two words
$ echo -e "overflow\ngrep" > b
# Search in file for lines containing one word from file b
$ grep --color --fixed-strings --file b /usr/share/dict/words
```

*Result on my system:*

```
overflow
overflow's
overflowed
overflowing
overflows
```

Add the *--only-matching* (-o) parameter to only get the words and not the whole line they appear in.

Comment: I just noticed: this answer has one of the same problems that I pointed out in another answer: it will display every word in `a.txt` that *contains* a word in `b.txt`.  For example, if `b.txt` contains the words `a` and `the`, you will get every word in `a.txt` that contains an `a`, and words that contain `the`, like `there`, `other`, and `lathe`.

Comment: If you want `the`'s without `lathe`'s, use `grep -w`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the words in the files are separated by LF and the words consist only of "nice" characters and there is no stray last LF in b.txt, then

```
egrep `tr '\n' '|' < b.txt` a.txt
```

might do the trick.

Comment: mmm not really, I get a confused output including all the words in b.txt followed by "no such file or directory", I would like to have the correct output instead i.e. just the words appearing in both. Maybe it is possible to first modify the file splitting the words in different lines and then comparing the lines

Comment: (0) Reyx_0: I don't understand how you got that output.  However, I would expect this command to display all the words in `a.txt`.  (1) RadovanGarabík: "Assuming ... there is no stray last LF in `b.txt`"?  I.e., you're assuming (and depending on the "fact") that the file is malformed.  That a hard assumption to justify.  (2) Even if you get past that problem, your command will display every word in `a.txt` that *contains* a word in `b.txt`.  For example, if `b.txt` contains `the cat caught a rat`, you will get every word in `a.txt` that contains an `a`, and words like `there` and `other`.

Comment: @G-Man Well, the original question had nothing about the presumed format the files are in, so I went for the simplest command, upon which more complicated scripts can be build. The assumption was that words are on separate lines, which is quite common in text corpora processing.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík: It seems like you don't get what I'm saying.  (1) The question refers to the files as `a.txt` and `b.txt`.  That implies that they are text files.  In fact, the question title says "text file" (twice).  And this site is unix.se.  Text files on Unix end with LF.  (2) Your command will report words ***that are not*** in `b.txt`.  An even simpler answer would be `echo foo`, but that's *wrong*.  Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler (attributed to Albert Einstein).  That fact that it's simple is not a justification for posting a *wrong* answer.

Answer (score -1):

While not working on a by word level, more in towards working on lines this could be of use to you or someone else looking for an answer.

```
diff --left-column --from-file=a.txt --to-file=b.txt
```

Compares from file a.txt to file b.txt outputting only common lines.